# Is CodeIgniter suitable for large intranet applications that do not use MySQL?

Tags: codeigniter

I don't really plan on using active record or any of the built in database constructs native to CodeIgniter for database access.  I have Oracle, SQL Server, and others.  I want to use PHP PDO (unless anyone thinks that's bad) because of the universal aspect of it.

I mainly want CI because of some of the built in libraries and MVC.  I also like that it is small and easy to work with.

2.x if it matters.

I did see other questions but none exactly about databases.

Thanks.

edit:  It's not that I don't think CI and PHP can take it with large websites.  This is solely about using multiple databases of varying companies.  I have mostly seen MySQL used with it.  I know I can use other databases but again, I don't know if it is more trouble than worth or what.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523682/possible-for-php-app-built-on-top-of-codeigniter-to-connect-to-a-mysql-and-a-mong/7526216#7526216

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL is the default just because of how widely-adopted it is, especially in the PHP world. Almost everyone has a *AMP stack to work on so it ends up being the main driver used in almost every example out there.

If you're not planning on using the database class, then it really doesn't matter what type of database you are using, just don't load the class. You can still use routing, helpers, libraries, and other CI features.

So yes, I do think it is suitable for your purposes.

Answer (score 3):

CodeIgniter was built with the idea of being the framework closest to native PHP that doesn't tell you what to do. The entire framework is modular and you are not required to use any single component.

Yes, it is absolutely suited to what you are doing. You can plug and play whatever DB driver you want and CI will not complain one bit.

I think CI is more suited for this role than any other of the 'big' frameworks.